# How to Extract the Text between the delimiters in Power BI Query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I want to add a custom column that extracts the text between the delimiters "~"

This is the input :

[image: Input column]

This is the output which I am expecting:

[image: Output Columns]

**I have tried below query, but its not working**

```
=Text.Select([#"Comments"]
{"A".."Z"} & {"1".."10"}&{"~"})
```

Could you please suggest me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works in powerquery (M)

It assumes data is coming from **Table1**, into **Column 1**
Adjust code if that is not true

It also assumes there is a space between the ending ~ and the next word

```
 let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
 #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(Source,"~ ","::",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Column1"}),
 #"Adjust edge case" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Replaced Value",{{"Column1", each if Text.End(_,1)="~" then Text.Start(_,Text.Length(_)-1) &"::" else _, type text}}),
 #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Adjust edge case", "Custom", each List.Difference(List.Transform(Text.Split([Column1],"~"), each Text.BeforeDelimiter(_,"::")),{""})),
 ColumnNames=List.Transform({1..List.Max(List.Transform(#"Added Custom"[Custom], each List.Count(_)))}, each "Data "&Text.From(_)),
 #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Adjust edge case", "Custom", each Text.Combine(List.Skip(List.Transform(Text.Split([Column1],"~"), each Text.BeforeDelimiter(_,"::")),1),"~")),
 #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Added Custom2", "Custom", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("~", QuoteStyle.Csv), ColumnNames)
 in  #"Split Column by Delimiter"
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your time , its not working when I tried in power query in power BI not excel sheet, can you please suggest me . If it is in Power BI what do i need to replace this in your query "Excel.CurrentWorkbook()"

Comment: This works in powerquery when the data is loaded from Table1 into column named Column1. I added photo.  If you have your own prior steps, then use those in place of my Source= row

Comment: Thank you again for the response, I am trying in Power BI power query, it seems to be its showing an error in  "Excel.CurrentWorkbook()" - kindly let me know what i should use in Power BI

Comment: Sorry, thats not my area of expertise.

Comment: OK, can you please suggest me in normal excel sheet where i need to write this query ?

Comment: Not sure what that means. You highlight your data in excel with data ... from table/range to get it into Powerquery, and above code is sample coded within powerquery that one could put into home... advanced editor...

Comment: I am able navigate to the power query in excel in advanced editor. when I copy your query in power query editor - I am seeing an error message - 'Table 1' not exist, can you please suggest me

Comment: I suggest you replace Table1 with the name of the table you are using.

Comment: @samshank102 You need to replace `Excel.CurrentWorkbook` with [Excel.WorkBook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/excel-workbook), then it will work in Power BI and Excel